# Google Play Game Services - Welcome Back Popup not shown

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to show "Welcome Back" popup after auto-signIn process as stated in the following documentation(FAQ part) :

https://developers.google.com/games/services/branding-guidelines

I have tried some methods like reconnecting etc. but it couldn't work. How can I show Welcome popup **without signing out the user and showing account selection popup again?**

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking does not appear to be possible.  According to the documentation at [Google Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.Builder.html#setShowConnectingPopup%28boolean,%20int%29)

> public GamesClient.Builder setShowConnectingPopup (boolean showConnectingPopup)
>
> Sets whether a "connecting" popup should be displayed automatically at the start of the sign-in flow. By default this is enabled.
>
> Note that this call will use the default gravity for the "connecting" popup, which will display the popup at the center of the screen. If you prefer that the popup appear in a different section of the screen, you can use setShowConnectingPopup(boolean, int), and provide a Gravity value.
>
> Parameters
> showConnectingPopup Whether or not to show a "connecting" popup at the beginning of the sign-in flow. Default behavior is for this to be true.
> Returns
> This Builder.

In watching the log output during a reconnect, I can find no discernible difference if performing it after backing out and immediately reconnecting (without logging out the user).  Only if the user if forcibly disconnected.

Yet, looking at the flow, and this documentation, and the branding guidelines, the behavior Should be to show the "Welcome" popup as long as the setShowConnectingPopup is set to true.

It would be nice if Bruno (hint hint) or any other Google Play Services could weigh-in on this, as it would appear we are violating the branding guidelines if we DON'T have the "Welcome" on each sign in (even though this is a new requirement as worded by Google, along with some of the other branding stuff)

As far as I can tell my original answer [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923079/google-play-game-services-custom-notification-welcome-back/18930706?noredirect=1#comment32498212_18930706) is still the only way to do this "Every" time, but if a user has multiple accounts, then yes the account selection will popup.

(my tests are on multiple devices, running from 4.1.32 and before.)